# Como exibir a data no input após a consulta

Tags: php, formulário

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";
    echo"<form class='navbar-form navbar-left' action='#'>";
      echo"DATA INICIAL:&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datainicio' id='datainicio' class='form-control'>";
      echo"DATA FINAL :&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datafinal' id='datafinal'class='form-control' >";
      echo"OCORRENCIA :&nbsp; &nbsp; <select class='form-control' id='ocorrencia' name='ocorrencia'>";

        $result= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM  ocorrencias") or die ("nÃ£o foi possivel fazer a pesquina no banco");
        while ($row       = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        $v_oc_id   = $row["oc_id"];
        $v_oc_desc = $row["oc_desc"];
              echo"<option value='$v_oc_id'>$v_oc_desc</option>";        
            }
        echo"</select>";
        echo"&nbsp; &nbsp; <button type='submit'class='btn btn-primary'><span class='  glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>";
echo"</form>";

 ?>
```

O que preciso, após a consulta que a data escolhida fique no campo data, como mostrado na imagem, ou seja após a consulta a data continue selecionada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: amigo vc pode tratar o form como html mesmo e não como echo do php, quanto a pergunta vc pode usar o value do input assim o valor que volta do banco aparece como deseja exemplo:

Comment: vc pode usar o value do input assim o valor que volta do banco aparece como deseja exemplo: ---> Não entendi bem,poderia me explicar melhor ?

Comment: exemplo  <input type='text' name='datafinal' id='datafinal' <?php echo $variaveldobanco['datafinal']?>class='form-control'>

Comment: vc quer pegar a data quem vemo da consulta do banco ou uma data que vc esta enviando pro banco?

Comment: A data que estou enviando - A pessoa coloca ali o período que quer consultar e com isso preciso que o período continue lá

Comment: agora entendi a pessoa coloca um intervalo e consulta o tipo de ocorrencia é isso? se for isso vc pode usar o post quando for consultar faca o teste, veja a resposta preencha a data e clique no submit. Quando a pagina for carregada vc podera pegar os dados do post e retornar nos inputs

Comment: @otaciojb acabo de editar minha resposta esqueci o `method='post'`, caso alguma das respostas estiverem corretas, considere validá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como seu objetivo e apresentar as datas após a consulta você pode recuperar esses dados pela variável post conforme mostra abaixo. Caso tenha duvida de um var_dump($_POST) e você vai ver todo o post que vc fez

```
<?php include "conexao.php"; ?>
        <form class='navbar-form navbar-left' action='#'>
            DATA INICIAL:&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datainicio' id='datainicio' value="<?php echo $_POST['datainicio']?>" class='form-control'>
            DATA FINAL :&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datafinal' id='datafinal' <?php echo $_POST['datafinal']?>class='form-control'>

            OCORRENCIA :&nbsp; &nbsp; <select class='form-control' id='ocorrencia' name='ocorrencia'>

                <?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  ocorrencias") or die("nÃ£o foi possivel fazer a pesquina no banco");
                while ($row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $v_oc_id   = $row["oc_id"];
                    $v_oc_desc = $row["oc_desc"];
                    echo"<option value='$v_oc_id'>$v_oc_desc</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <button type='submit'class='btn btn-primary'><span class='  glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>
        </form>

        ?>
```

Comment: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: datafinal in <b>/var/www/html/sistema/principal.php</b> on line <b>134</b><br /> , como se inicia sem data retorna isso, e mesmo após a consulta continua retornando isso

Comment: isso é porque a variável post esta vazia ela só será preenchida depois do submit

Comment: @ThallesDaniel Para que isso não aconteça, pode se definir previamente as variáveis do tipo `string` com um espaço em braco `space`, note não basta apenas aspas simples é necessário espaço.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

$datainicio='';
if(isset($_POST["datainicio"])){ $datainicio = $_POST["datainicio"]; }

$datafinal='';
if(isset($_POST["datafinal"])){ $datafinal = $_POST["datafinal"]; }

    echo"<form class='navbar-form navbar-left' action='#'>";
      echo"DATA INICIAL:&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datainicio' value='$datainicio' id='datainicio' class='form-control'>";
      echo"DATA FINAL :&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datafinal' value='$datafinal' id='datafinal'class='form-control' >";
      echo"OCORRENCIA :&nbsp; &nbsp; <select class='form-control' id='ocorrencia' name='ocorrencia'>";

            $v_oc_desc = 'v_oc_desc';
            echo"<option value='$v_oc_id'>$v_oc_desc</option>";        

        echo"</select>";
        echo"&nbsp; &nbsp; <button type='submit'class='btn btn-primary'><span class='  glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>";
echo"</form>";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode recuperar os dados da seguinte forma, como já mencionado nas respostas anteriores, através da variável global `$_POST`.

Em relação ao erro referido nos comentários da resposta anterior :

`<br/><b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: datafinal in<b>/var/www/html/sistema/principal.php</b> on line <b>134</b><br/>, "como se inicia sem data retorna isso, e mesmo após a consulta continua retornando isso"`

Para que isso não aconteça, pode se definir previamente as variáveis do tipo string com um espaço em branco `'espaço'`, note não basta apenas aspas simples é necessário espaço.

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

$datainicio=' ';
if(isset($_POST["datainicio"])){$datainicio = $_POST["datainicio"];}
$datafinal=' ';if(isset($_POST["datafinal"])){$datafinal = $_POST["datafinal"];} 
    echo"<form class='navbar-form navbar-left' action='#' method='post'>";
    echo"DATA INICIAL:&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datainicio' id='datainicio' value='".$datainicio."' class='form-control'>";
    echo"DATA FINAL :&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='text' name='datafinal' id='datafinal' value='".$datafinal."' class='form-control'>";
    echo"OCORRENCIA :&nbsp; &nbsp; <select class='form-control' id='ocorrencia' name='ocorrencia'>";

    $result= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM  ocorrencias") or die ("nÃ£o foi possivel fazer a pesquina no banco");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $v_oc_id   = $row["oc_id"];
        $v_oc_desc = $row["oc_desc"];
        echo"<option value='$v_oc_id'>$v_oc_desc</option>";        
    }

    echo"</select>";
    echo"<button type='submit'class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>";
    echo"</form>";
?>
```

Dedique um pouco de tempo, com esta pergunta :[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)